# Javascript phone number validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to make sure phone numbers are entered correctly. They are UK numbers and cannot contain any symbols or letters. They must be 11 in length.

So I have tried the following:

```
else if (phone == null || !phone.toString().match(/^[-]?\d*\.?\d*$/)){
```

But this actually allows any length and even blank input.

What should I do to validate phone numbers? I'm not that experienced with Javascript.

Comment: Where did you get `phone` from? Show the part in where `phone` is assigned. If `phone = someElement.value`, `phone == null` can be omitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use a regex, but I'd allow the user to add other characters too, for readability. This could work, if your phone number must be 11 digits in total:

```
/^(?:\W*\d){11}\W*$/.test(phone.value)
```

`\W` is anything but digits, letters and underscore, but as it's intended to allow for spaces, dot, hyphens and slashes, you could use `[ .\-\/]` instead.

After the field passes validation, you can clean it up, turning it into a more standard format, usually small groups of digits (it depends on the habits in your country) but likely starting with removing all non-digit characters.

```
phone.value = phone.value.replace(/\W+/g, '');
```

If you allow for international access codes, or other prefixes, the number of digits may not be fixed, but actually depend on the prefix.

Answer (score 8):

The regexp to match exactly 11 digits is `/^\d{11}$/`.

Answer (score 5):

UK numbers are NOT 11 digits long. They are a mix of 9 or 10 digits not including the 0 trunk code or `+44` country prefix.

The rules are somewhat complicated but can be defined in a handful of RegEx patterns.

The first step has to be to strip off the `+44`, `00 44`, `011 44`, `+44 (0)`, `00 44 (0)`, `011 44 (0)` or `0` prefix before investigating the rest of the number.

```
Pattern: ^(\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)(44)\)?[\s-]?)?\(?0?(?:\)[\s-]?)?([1-9]\d{1,4}\)?[\d\s-]+)((?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$
```

Use the above pattern to extract the `44` from `$2` to know that international format was used, otherwise assume national format if `$2` is null.

Extract the optional extension number details from `$4` and store them for later use.

Extract the NSN (including spaces, hyphens and parentheses) from `$3`. Remove those spaces, hyphens and parentheses and use the RegEx pattern below to validate the length and initial digits.

```
Pattern: ^((1[1-9]|2[03489]|3[0347]|5[56]|7[04-9]|8[047]|9[018])\d{8}|(1[2-9]\d|[58]00)\d{6}|8(001111|45464\d))$
```

Much more detailed patterns are available elsewhere, right down to individual area codes.

Answer (score 1):

I personally test for

```
/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/
```

or

```
/^((0|\+44)7\d{3}\s?\d{6})$/
```

if I want to single out mobile numbers specifically. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The next line matches exactely 11 digits on phone:

```
else if (/^\d{11}$/.test(phone)) {
```

I assume `phone` is a string, as in:

```
var phone = someHtmlFormElement.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something more like this: `/^\d{5} \d{6}$/` ?

Also don't forget if you are submitting this to a server that whatever validation you do on the client will need to be repeated on the server, and you cannot trust someone won't bypass your javascript

Answer (score -1):

At 
[www.aa-asterisk.org.uk](https://www.aa-asterisk.org.uk/index.php/Regular_Expressions_for_Validating_and_Formatting_GB_Telephone_Numbers)
you can find various patterns related to UK phone numbers for example:

Pattern:

```
 ^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$
```

> The above pattern matches optional opening parentheses, followed by 00
>   or 011 and optional closing parentheses, followed by an optional space
>   or hyphen, followed by optional opening parentheses. Alternatively,
>   the initial opening parentheses are followed by a literal + without a
>   following space or hyphen. Any of the previous two options are then
>   followed by 44 with optional closing parentheses, followed by optional
>   space or hyphen, followed by optional 0 in optional parentheses,
>   followed by optional space or hyphen, followed by optional opening
>   parentheses (international format). Alternatively, the pattern matches
>   optional initial opening parentheses followed by the 0 trunk code
>   (national format).

eg for matching a mobile number you can use following function

```
    function isMobile(v) {

        //handle leading 0
        if (v.indexOf('0') === 0) {
            v = v.substring(1);
        }

        var mobile_valid = /^7(?:[1-4]\d\d|5(?:0[0-8]|[13-9]\d|2[0-35-9])|624|7(?:0[1-9]|[1-7]\d|8[02-9]|9[0-689])|8(?:[014-9]\d|[23][0-8])|9(?:[04-9]\d|1[02-9]|2[0-35-9]|3[0-689]))\d{6}$/.test(v);
        var pager_valid = /^76(?:0[012]|2[356]|4[0134]|5[49]|6[0-369]|77|81|9[39])\d{6}$/.test(v);

        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_numbering
        var personal_number = /^70\d{8}$/.test(v);

        if (pager_valid || mobile_valid || personal_number) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```