# Mobile or phone number validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate phone or mobile number in javascript.
It should match the following types:
`+91-9198387083`
`9198387083`
`09198387083`
It is a 10 digit number with one of these four prefixes `'+91-'`, `'+91'`, `'0'` or `''`

Can someone suggest me a regex expression in javascript which matches all the three types.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386054, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286046

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd using something like this:

```
/^(\+91-|\+91|0)?\d{10}$/
```

This is very specific about one of your three allowable prefixes (or no prefix) followed by exactly 10 digits and no extra characters on the beginning of end of the string.

Test app with both valid and invalid phone numbers here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/K9bjL/

Comment: @DevashishDixit - you were very quick.  I fixed that issue within a minute or so of posting and how there's a test app that you can plug any test values you want into.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

`/\+?[0-9]+-?[0-9]/`

Comment: This is not very restrictive as it allows any prefix and only matches the first digit of the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

10 digit number with one of these four prefixes `+91-`, `+91`, `0` or :

```
/(\+91-?|0)?\d{10}/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
+7 (123) 45-67-890
8(123)381-198-2
and etc.
```

My simply mask for all of similar phones

```
/^[+]?(\d[^\d]*){11}$/
```