# Validate UK phone number allow plus sign only at start

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the below regex for UK telephone numbers:

```
function ValidatePhone(phone) {
    var expr = /^(?:\W*\d){11}\W*$/;
    return expr.test(phone);
}
```

Also, I am using javascript to restrict user to enter only numbers, + and () as below:

```
onlyNumAllowed.on("keypress", function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 43 && charCode > 31 && charCode != 32 && charCode != 40 && charCode != 41 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
});
```

Everything is working fine except for that

> I want plus(+) sign to be only at the start if at all it is entered.

Comment: var expr = /^?+(?:\W*\d){11}\W*$/;   ?

Comment: take a look to [UK numbers are NOT 11 digits long.....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286046/javascript-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Just a heads up, javascript can be disabled. So you might want to validate this server-side as well.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the regex you provided is not working

Comment: \+\d{2}\(\d{1}\)\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{4} try this

Comment: @TKHN does not work

Comment: @HDev007 U may refer this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch04s03.html

Comment: @HDev007 can you specify all the rules for the pattern you want? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @ShammelLee my regex i.e. /^\+?(?:\d\s?){11,13}$/  this is working fine but one thing is not being done ..like i can enter in textbox like +1+2+3 so on I want to prevent user to enter + onlyonce and at beginning

Comment: @Ok got it. Can you give me an example of a valid UK phone number?

Comment: 12345 1234567 ,+123456789011 I am able to validate these but not able to prevent user from entering + sign in between of textbox

Comment: You need to test the regex inside `onlyNumAllowed.on("keypress")`

Comment: Change `^(?:\W*` to `^(?:\s*\+?)` and change `\W*$` to `\s*$`